# React Native ListView slow to load

Tags: ios, listview, react-native

I have a simple ListView which seems to take a long time to load its items. I've tested in Release mode, and its taking about 3 seconds to load the whole page. If I set `initialListSize={1}` I can see it building the list item by item.

The ListView JSX code:

```
<ListView
      dataSource={this.state.dataSource}
      renderRow={this.renderRow}
      renderSeparator={(sectionID, rowID) => <View key={`${sectionID}-${rowID}`} style={styles.separator} />}
      style={styles.listView}
      initialListSize={1}
    />
```

And the renderRow method:

```
  renderRow(row) {
    // console.log ('rendering scale row: ' + row.numerator + ':' + row.denominator );
    return (
      <TouchableHighlight onPress={() => this.pressRow(row)} underlayColor="grey">
        <View style={styles.rowContainer}>
          <Text style={styles.rowText}>{row.hasOwnProperty('label') ? row.label : row.numerator + ':' + row.denominator}</Text>
          <Text style={styles.rowText}>{row.hasOwnProperty('label') ? row.numerator + ':' + row.denominator : ''}</Text>
        </View>
      </TouchableHighlight>
    );
  }
```

I'm not doing anything very complicated in renderRow... and the data had already been fetched in a previous view and passed in via `props`.

Is there something I don't know about that could be affecting load/render time?

This is iOS only and on an iPhone 4S. Only 12-21 rows in my tests.

I should also add that the core of the app is using the JUCE C++ framework and running some audio processing in one of the views. I have an audio processing thread that is only run when that view is visible - all other views (including the one with this ListView) will stop the audio processing thread. I've tried also stopping the audio thread in a similar manner but it did not make any difference.

Comment: Code looks ok. Device or simulator? iOS only? How many rows?

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this is going to help you, but I can think of three things you can try...

1. `cmd`+`T` will toggle "slow animations" on/off. This is a long shot
2. If you are writing to the console.log, comment out those lines. They can surprisingly bog things down considerably sometimes.
3. Turn off dev mode. You shouldn't need to, but worth a shot

Comment: I tried commenting out console.log and testing in Release mode - the rows still take time to load.. haven't tried cmd + T though.

Comment: Let me know if command+T helps, be sure to hit the key combo while in the simulator. If that doesn't fix it, take a video so we can see what you're seeing

Comment: I'm only seeing this on device, haven't tested in simulator as yet (the simulator takes ages to load and slows down my ageing macbook!)

Comment: Ah, well then that's definitely not going to solve your concern. Sorry I couldn't help.

Answer (score 1):

Better start using FlatList or SectionList since ListView is now Deprecated.

https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/listview.html

There are few Caveats like you must use a FLUX/ REDUX or RELAY. Please Checkout the details here (Features/Caveats) 
https://facebook.github.io/react-native/blog/2017/03/13/better-list-views.html