# Pre-render ListView in React Native

Tags: ios, listview, rendering, react-native

I'm having issues with a slow rendering ListView in React Native on an iPhone 4S. See [React Native ListView slow to load](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35119790/react-native-listview-slow-to-load) for details on that issue.

One workaround I thought of is to pre-render the view, as all the data for it will be available in the previous view on the navigation stack. Is this possible in React Native?

Comment: Is it rendering slow when you are not debugging or running in dev? How many items are in your list? Thanks.

Comment: See the linked question for details - I have tested in a Release build, with jsbundle on the device, with only 12 items in the list. Data already exists before the view is loaded just passed via props.

Answer (score 1):

Use React Native's [FlatList](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/flatlist.html), which has much better performance.